# Integral over region bounded

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

- $\int_{E} f$ where $f(x, y)=x^{2} y$ and $E$ is the region in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ between the line $y=x-2$ and the parabola $x=4-y^{2}$ Use Funini's thereom

My Attempt. [The graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%3Dx-2%20and%20x%3D4-y%5E2)

Then we evaluate $\int_{-2}^{1} \int_{-2-y}^{4-y^2} {x^2y}$ $dx dy.$

May you check my attempt? May you check as proof-writing that is there a missing in the proof?

Comment: Note that $E$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, so $f$ is bounded. It follows that $\int E f<\infty$, so that we may use Fubini's theorem to interchange the order of integration.

Comment: but I didn't use fubini since I didn't need to interchange the order of integration

Comment: Fubini's theorem also tells us that $\int_E f$ exists and can be computed as either of the iterated integrals.

Comment: Thanks for comment 